# Random.nextInt(1); only returning 1

Tags: java, random, minecraft

This is my minecraft mod algorithm. For some reason it appears that `rand.nextInt(1);` only returns 1. Why?

```
public void generate(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    Arrays.fill(wc,null);
    int c = generateCat();//Generates a int of 1-16 randomly
    int i = 0;
    int xi = 0;
    int x = getCoordX();
    int y = getCoordY();
    int maxc = 0;
    boolean d1 = true;
    boolean d2 = false;
    boolean d3 = false;
    boolean d4 = false;
    boolean loop = true;

    wc[0] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);//Here the starting object is generated
    x=x-1;
    if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){//Here the c value (is supposed to have a 50% chance of reducing) But it never does EVER!?
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        c--;
        wc[1] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);//Here the c value (is supposed to have a 50% chance of reducing) But it never does EVER!?
    }else{
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        wc[1] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }
    x=x+2;
    if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        c--;
        wc[2] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }else{
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        wc[2] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }
    x=x-1;
    y++;

    if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        c--;
        wc[3] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }else{
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        wc[3] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }
    y=y-2;
    if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        c--;
        wc[4] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }else{
        c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
        wc[4] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
    }
    y=wc[0].coordY;
    x=wc[0].coordX-2;
    i=5;

    while(loop){
                d1=true;
                while(d1){
                    if(chunkExists(x+1,y)){
                        if(getHNChunkCat(x,y)>maxc)maxc=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                        if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            c--;
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }else{
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }
                        x++;
                        y++;
                        i++;
                    }else{
                        d1=false;
                    }   
                }
                d2=true;
                while(d2){
                    if(chunkExists(x,y-1)){
                        if(getHNChunkCat(x,y)>maxc)maxc=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                        if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            c--;
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }else{
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }
                        x++;
                        y--;
                        i++;
                    }else{
                        d2=false;
                    }   
                }
                d3=true;
                while(d3){
                    if(chunkExists(x-1,y)){
                        if(getHNChunkCat(x,y)>maxc)maxc=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                        if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            c--;
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }else{
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }
                        x--;
                        y--;
                        i++;
                    }else{
                        d3=false;
                    }   
                }
                d4=true;
                while(d4){

                    if(chunkExists(x-1,y)){
                        if(getHNChunkCat(x,y)>maxc)maxc=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                        if(rand.nextInt(1)==1){
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            c--;
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }else{
                            c=getHNChunkCat(x,y);
                            wc[i] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,c);
                        }
                        x--;
                        y++;
                        i++;
                        if(chunkExists(x,y)){
                        d4=false;
                        break;
                    }
                    }else{
                        d4=false;
                    }   
                }

                y=wc[0].coordY;
                x=wc[0].coordX;
                xi=0;

                while(true){
                    if(!chunkExists(x-xi,y)){
                        x=x-xi;
                        break;
                    }else{
                        xi++;
                    }
                }

                if(maxc==0){
                    loop=false;
                }
    }

    cleanChunks();
    WEATHER.addChunkArray(wc2);

}
```

Ive also tried

```
 wc[1] = new WeatherChunk(world,x,y,(getHNChunkCat()-rand.nextInt(1)));
```

Comment: `nextInt( x )` returns an `int` between `0` inclusive and `x` ***exclusive***.

Comment: The argument of the `nextInt` method is the upper argument. So it's an integer range between 0 and 1.

Comment: it returns only 0, never 1

Comment: Yes, I agree. Where did 1 come from? One is exclusive.

Answer (score 10):

You have not debugged enough because that is impossible. It's true that you will only receive one value but it's `0`, not `1`.

From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (**exclusive**)

If you want a 50% chance, I suggest you turn it into `nextInt(2)` or as @Flynn1179 suggests: [`nextBoolean()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean()).

Comment: Don't need `nextInt(2)`, just use `nextBoolean()`

Comment: Thank you but i am pretty sure that i have gotten the same thing to work  in another place time to go over and fix everything

Comment: Then it must have been a different situation because it's impossible to do it the way you laid out in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get a decimal between 0 and 1? Use this:

```
Math.random() // returns a random double
```

The `nextInt` method only returns a random number between 0 and the specified argument, but not including the argument. Thus you should always be getting 0.